# How to identify a query that returns a result set in Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata

I am writing some simple program that parses queries into two buckets:

1) those who do not have a result set (like INSERT, UPDATE, CREATE)

2) and those who do (like SELECT)

As far as I understand, as long   as a query starts with `SEL` or `WITH` substrings it ALWAYS has a result set. Is this correct ? I am sure about `SEL`, but not quite sure about `WITH`. Is it possible that a query starts with `WITH` and does not have a result set ?

Comment: I believe your assumption is correct about `WITH` being `SELECT` only. You can't use `With` with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `CREATE`, etc... In fact the only keyword allowed after a CTE is `SELECT` and a handful of temporal keywords that would only eventually lead to a `SELECT`. This parsing might get a little more difficult when you hit keywords like 'USING' or 'LOCKING' though.

Comment: Thank you very much I completely forgot about LOCKING .

Answer (score 0):

In Java (for instance)

```
Connection conn = ... // connect here
if (conn.createStatement().execute( sql )) {
  // it's a select statement
}
```

Your SQL can start also with comments and be submittable. Another example is an anonymous block:

```
BT;
  select user; 
ET;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're ignoring SQL that "hides" the logic in this split. E.G a macro can contain SELECT and/or DML. In case you have a EXEC myMacro you have to get the DDL of the macro an parse this one.

I would try the approach of requesting the EXPLAIN of the SQL. In this case the RDBMS takes over the parsing and you just have to scan the explain whether (at the end) something is send to the client (they will have an resultset) or inserted/merged into an table.